# About the economic interpretation of the dual of a L.P

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

I am reading the Bazaraa, Linear Programming, and there is something I do not understand about the economic interpretation of the dual
Exactly the part where says

> If the right hand side $b_i$ is perturbed slightly, since the current basic feasible solution remains feasible, we maintain its
> optimality

How do I know that B is still feasible and optimal?

I understand that if I perturb some $ b_i $ I would be moving a hyperplane and therefore modifying the feasible region, I also know that the objective function does not change, but I don't know what else to do.

[image]

Comment: I think I have an answer. Suppose we increment some $b_i$ by $\delta$. To remain $B$ feasible then we only need that $B^{-1}(b+\delta e_i)\geq 0$, and since the the vector on the right side does not influence in the optimality condition , then it remains optimal.